# Do you have performance problems when you work on Visual Studio projects via a network share?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

We have tremendous problems with Visual Studio (2008, if that matters) locking up and slowing down when accessing projects over a network drive.  It can take several minutes to open a large Web site project through a mapped drive, and saving even a single file can take a minute or more.

I fired up Wireshark and watched the traffic.  VS, it seems, requests massive amounts of files from the network -- there's an enormous amount of SMB traffic.  I've done some research, and this traffic seems to stem from two situations.

1. VS has to have everything in its own process to provide Intellisense.
2. VS needs to have all the source in order to compile the project.

All the advice I've read seems to boil down to the same thing: work locally, not on a remote machine, then push your code to an integration server via source control.

This would sure solve our problems (VS is quite fast working locally), but what if you *can't* work locally?  What if the project and the infrastructure required to run it is too large and complicated to be replicated on everyone's individual machines?

We've gone 'round this problem a couple times, and the only way we can figure to work on these projects is direct access via a mapped drive.  However, the VS slowness and lockups are really becoming a problem.

One solution: we installed VS on the server and work on the projects directly on the servers via RDP.  Seriously.

So, I ask:

What does everyone else do?  Do you work via the network, or do you replicate projects locally?  If remotely, do you suffer from VS performance issues.

Comment: I'm not even sure how you manage to do this with large websites, the half open connection limits in windows should cause problems with the file change notifications that visual studio / iis / webdev use.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "project and the infrastructure required to run it is too large and complicated"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We work locally and use SVN to keep all our code on the server.

I find VS 2008 quite slow working locally sometimes so I wouldn't fancy working on a network share.

Comment: This is what we ended up doing.  We implemented CruiseControl.net to manage the integration.

Answer (score 3):

Trying to compile over a network share is horribly slow using visual studio. Your start times will be bad as the intellisense database is regenerated. Each compilation has to go over the network multiple times. Linking takes forever.

If you need the output of your compilation on the network, I'd recommend doing your compile locally and defining a post-build command to copy the results to your share.

If, as you say, you cannot pull everything locally then I'd suggest your project is too big and needs to be broken up into more manageable chunks. For a multi-tier application, break it up by tier and invest in some form of continuous integration (e.g. CruiseControl) to automatically build individual pieces. In this way you can work locally on an particular piece and pull the pre-build portions from CI for the other pieces of the application.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not terribly surprised that using VS to load projects over a network share has performance issues.  VS (in any language) is constantly getting information from files in the project.  Once you start loading this over a network you're at the mercy of the underlying network connection.  All lags and access issues will directly translate into VS having an issue loading file contents.

I would advise copying the solution locally and using some form of source code control to sync the project on the share.

Answer (score 1):

If the code is too complicated to install on everyone's machine, then don't put it on everyone's machine. Does everyone need to have *everything* in order to do productive work?

Answer (score 1):

I have 79 projects in my solution that I work with. Several hundred thousand lines of code. I pull my source down everyday from TFS and build it; it's a lot of code, but it's a far better solution than trying to work over a network share.

Answer (score 1):

A more legitimate situation of having the source code on a share is when one has a non-Windows host on which a (number of) virtual Windows machine is running.

I have this exact situation where my desktop machine (the *host*) is running Debian and I use VMware to run various virtual Windows machines (the *guests*), including one that has Visual Studio installed so that I can target Windows OS's.  Having the source code on a Samba share on the host machine has the following pro's:

- The source is not duplicated, so there is no way to confuse different copies while working on several virtual machines at the same time.
- I have full control over the source from my preferred OS.
- I can turn on and off any of the virtual machines, or roll back to a snapshot, without the risk of loosing changes.
- I can build (etc.) from the **same** source on several machines **without** having to commit changes before the source fully tested (reason: I have to use Subversion <1.5).

The *only* problem with this setup is that Visual Studio (6,7,8,9) is painfully slow.

I have mounted the partition (on which the share lies) with "relatime" and this works in as far as the disk activity on the share moderate, but Visual Studio keeps the (virtual) network card occupied all the time.

Any solutions to this would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar problems everytime I worked (work = anything else then just copy / paste files) over a network drive. The problem occured with ZendStudio and Eclipse.

Why not use any kind of source control?

Answer (score 0):

When working on Windows based projects I've always worked locally.

Once at a unix shop (AIX iirc) developers would work via NFS mount and checkin/checkout via RCS...

Answer (score 0):

I'm using VS2005 across to a network share and not having any performance issues.  However, it is a new server (Windows Server 2008).  I don't have any other data points for VS since using it at work is relatively new for me.

However, some datapoints from using Netbeans for previous projects on a network share...  Local build time for my project was 2 minutes on Vista, on a fast dual-core AMD 64-bit machine.  For a network share project, on a Server 2003 box, it was 20 minutes.  Building that same project from an ancient Tablet PC (1ghz, single core) running XP locally was around 5 minutes.  Interestingly enough, the Tablet PC could build on the Server 2003 box in the same 5 minutes.

For those asking "why" on the network share.  The network share is automatically backed up, archived, etc.  Also, that way I can very easily look at the same projects from multiple machines without having to worry about pushing back into the repository, etc.  Once you've gone to having your dev stuff on a device where you can get to it from anywhere/anything, you'll never want to do local storage again!

Comment: Source control repositories can be automatically backed up too. Sharing source over a network share is something out of the stone age, sorry.

Comment: @unforgiven3 Yes, the repository is also backed up automatically.  The purpose of the code residing on the server is not to avoid a repository.  It's to make my "local copy" as resilient as the repository.  If I lose my machine in the middle of the day and haven't committed yet, I just jump on another machine rather than starting over where the last commit left off...

Answer (score 0):

I have performance problems via network anything, they just aren't good enough yet.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was common knowledge that disk-speed is one of the major "slowness" factors when it comes to using VS in Windows. Most dev machines I've built have had projects located on 10k RPM RAID0 drives, or at least a single 10k RPM drive. And even then it seems slow sometimes. Just the way it is, I suppose, until VS2009/VS2010 fixes it? :)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, this lag when working on a network share is 99% due to Intellisense. Disable it and you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

disabling Intellisense indeed speeds up saving and opening files trough a UNC share dramatically

http://blogs.msdn.com/saraford/archive/2007/12/03/did-you-know-how-to-turn-off-intellisense-by-default.aspx

but then again, as stated in other comments, you might as well use a good text editor

Answer (score 0):

I've also experienced the problems with performance mentioned above. It seems to vary from project to project, but I did find one way of speeding up performance **significantly** for some project types.

Following the advice in [this article](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/364/how-do-i-allow-my-visual-studio-net-projects-to-run-from-a-network-location) made a previously unusable project on a network location (it would take minutes to open one file) perform almost like a local project. The basic gist is that you need to grant `FULL TRUST` to the network location:

To grant permission to all your projects in your Visual Studio Projects folder located on the network, follow these 8 steps:

> Open Microsoft .NET Framework 1.1 (or 2.0) Configuration which you'll
>   find under Administrative Tools in the Control Panel.
>
> Expand Runtime Security Policy | Machine, | Code Groups | All_Code |
>   LocalIntranet_Zone In the right-hand pane, click Add a Child Code
>   Group.
>
> In the dialog that follows choose Create a new code group and fill in
>   a Name like Visual Studio Projects.
>
> Optionally, provide a Description for the Code Group. (You'll see the
>   description when you click a Code Group in the left tree, helping you
>   identify the various Code Groups you may have) .
>
> In the Condition Type drop down, choose URL
>
> For the URL field, type something like this:
>
> ```
> file://YourServer/My Documents/Visual Studio Projects/*
> ```
>
> Under Use existing permission set, choose FullTrust (that is, if you
>   trust your own applications. If you don't, choose a different
>   permission set or create a new one).

Not sure why this works, but it made a previously unusable NET 2.0 project perform significantly better.

Original article: http://imar.spaanjaars.com/364/how-do-i-allow-my-visual-studio-net-projects-to-run-from-a-network-location

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.  I have a local copy of our build system, which expects certain drive letters, and was also experiencing slowness.

I have solved the problem by adding the following registry keys:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices]
"R:"="\DosDevices\D:\devel\build
"S:"="\DosDevices\D:\devel\src"

Note that the double '\'s above are part of the .reg file format.  When using regedit use single '\' throughout.

My build times were divided by 3. :)

I found the info in the wikipedia article on the SUBST command.